# ruby middleman hash traversal

Tags: ruby, hash, middleman

New to hashes. I've got a hash from middleman data file which is automatically generated by [contentful_middleman](https://github.com/contentful/contentful_middleman). Basically

```
data.space.homepage = {
  "PCWLCTeTCKsaoGGSQOc6i"=>{
    "id"=>"PCWLCTeTCKsaoGGSQOc6i",
    "pageTitle"=>"Page Title",
    "pageContent"=>"page content",
  }
}
```

Because `PCWLCTeTCKsaoGGSQOc6i` is automatically generated I have to be able to reference it without using this key.

I don't know why exactly but the underscore here gets me where I need to be:

```
        <% data.space.homepage.each do |_, item| %>
          <h1 class="tag"><%= item.pageTitle %></h1>
        <% end %>
```

I'd like to be able to access pageTitle and pageContent without looping over the data but I can't figure out if that's possible without explicitly using the key `PCWLCTeTCKsaoGGSQOc6i`

Comment: When iterating over a Hash, we use `|k, v|` to represent the key and value within the block. If we are using the value but not the key, standard is to use `|_, v|` to indicate that the key is not used. In your case, `|_, item|` indicates that you are representing the value with the variable `item` and you are not using the key in your block.

Comment: You can also call on .keys on the hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `homepage` is a hash with a single pair of key/value, you can use :

```
title, content = data.space.homepage.values.first.values_at('pageTitle', 'pageContent')
title   #=> "Page Title"
content #=> "page content"
```

The id is :

```
homepage.keys.first #=> "PCWLCTeTCKsaoGGSQOc6i"
```

Comment: nice thanks! `data.space.homepage.values.first` works great.